# Does a hypo-exponential distribution become deterministic as the number of phases approach $\infty$?

Tags: limits, statistics, probability-distributions, limits-without-lhopital, probability-limit-theorems

A [hypo-exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution) is a more general case of the [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution). The former has different transition rates $\lambda_i,$ $i=1,2,\dots,N$ while the latter uses the same transition rates $\lambda_i = \lambda,$ $i=1,2,\dots,N$. Furthermore, it is easy to show that the Erlang distribution becomes deterministic as the number of phases increases to $\infty$. This requires making use of its squared coefficient of variation $CV(X_N) = \operatorname{Var}(X_N)/(\mathbb{E}[X_N])^2$ where $\operatorname{Var}(X_N) = N/\lambda^2$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_N] = N/\lambda$. Hence, $CV(X_N) = 1/N$ such that $\lim_{N\to \infty } 1/N = 0$. Thus the distribution becomes deterministic.

I conjecture that the same happens to the hypo-exponential distribution. If this conjecture is correct, I would like to show this similarly as was done with the Erlang distribution. I start with the expected value
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_N] = \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{ \lambda_n}
$$
and variance
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X_N) = \sum_{n=1}^N  \frac{1}{\lambda_n^2}
$$
where it is understood that $\lambda_n > 0, $ $n=1,2,\dots,N$. The coefficient of variation thus follows as
$$
CV(X_N) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{ \lambda_n^2}}{\left( \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{ \lambda_n} \right)^2}
$$
where the denominator can be expanded
$$
CV(X_N) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{ \lambda_n^2}}{\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{ \lambda_n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_n}\sum_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq n}}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_j}}.
$$
This makes it clear that $CV(X_N) < 1$. The next step then results in

$$
CV(X_N) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_n}\sum_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq n}}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_j}}{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_n^2}} }
$$
or more succinctly
$$
CV(X_N) = \frac{1}{1+ \Psi(X_N)}
$$
where
$$
\Psi(X_N) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq n}}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_n\lambda_j}}{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\lambda_n^2}}.
$$
Now if we were to show that $\Psi(X_N)$ is a monotonically increasing function of $N$ then we are sorted. Unfortunately, I have not been able to do so yet. I will probably resort to plotting $\Psi(X_N)$ as to determine this. However, that is not rigorous at all.

Can you please help show me if it is a monotonically increasing function?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting an answer to my own question. I have chosen not to place it as an edit in the question as I would like this post to reflect that there is at least one answer. Furthermore, the question is still open to alternative solutions.

**TL;DR**: $\Psi(X_N)$ is not monotonically increasing in $N$ but seems to be increasing in $N$ or so simulations would suggest. As such, one cannot conclude that the hypo-exponential distribution becomes deterministic as one adds infinitely more phases. However, in practice we do observe that $CV(X_N)$ decreases close to zero.

**Long answer:** we are going to have a look at the following:
$$
\Delta_N := \Psi(X_{N+1}) - \Psi(X_N).
$$
The goal is to determine/characterise the sign of $\Delta_N$. Note that in the above, $\Psi(X_N)$ makes use of $\vec{\lambda}_{N} = [\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N]^\top$ while $\Psi(X_N)$ shares the same $N$ values but with the addition of $\lambda_{N+1}$, i.e. $\vec{\lambda}_{N+1} = [\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N,\lambda_{N+1}]^\top$. Furthermore, we need to define the combination function $C(\vec{\lambda},n)$ that returns all $n$ length combinations $\vec{c}$ that can be made from the elements of $\vec{\lambda}$. These combinations will be returned as $\vec{c}$. For example $C([\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3],2) = \{ [\lambda_1,\lambda_2],[\lambda_1,\lambda_3],[\lambda_2,\lambda_3] \}$

So $\Psi(X_N)$ changes due to the addition of $\lambda_{N+1}$. Hence, it makes sense to solve for $\lambda_{N+1}$ in $\Delta_N = 0$. Call this solution $\lambda_{N+1}^*$. It follows as:
$$
\lambda_{N+1}^* = \frac{\left( \sum_{\vec{c} \in C\left(\vec{\lambda_N},N-2\right)} \prod_{\lambda_i \in \vec{c}}  \lambda_i\right) \left( \prod_{i=1}^N \lambda_i^2 \right) }{\left( \sum_{\vec{c} \in C\left(\vec{\lambda_N},N-1\right)} \prod_{\lambda_i \in \vec{c}}  \lambda_i\right)\left( \sum_{\vec{c} \in C\left(\vec{\lambda_N},N-1\right)} \prod_{\lambda_i \in \vec{c}}  \lambda_i^2\right)}, \quad N \geq 3.
$$
If $N=2$ then replace the first product of the numerator with 1. If $N=1$ then the solution is trivial/obvious as $\lambda_{2}^* = 0$. This solution was obtained through the help of Sympy.

We now have the following three cases:
$$
\Delta_N \in \begin{cases} \mathbb{R}_{>0}, & \lambda_{N+1} > \lambda_{N+1}^*\\
 \{0\}, &  \lambda_{N+1} = \lambda_{N+1}^*\\
\mathbb{R}_{<0}, & \lambda_{N+1} < \lambda_{N+1}^*\end{cases}.
$$
So depending on the value of $\lambda_{N+1}$ relative to $\lambda_{N+1}^*$, it becomes clear that $\Psi(X_N)$ can increase or decrease in $N$. However, we need it to be monotonically increasing such that $\lim_{N\to \infty }\Psi(X_N) = \infty$ as this would prove that $\lim_{N\to \infty }CV(X_N) = 0$.

There might of course exist special cases. The first one that jumps to mind is setting all the $\lambda_i$ to a single value $\lambda$. This of course gives the Erlang distribution for which we know $\lim_{N\to \infty }CV(X_N) = 0$. I would like to just verify our solution $\lambda_{N+1}^*$ through showing that for the Erlang distribution we have
$$
\lambda_{N+1}^* = \frac{\lambda}{N}.
$$
Hence, $\lambda_{N+1} = \lambda \geq \lambda_{N+1}^*$, $N=1,2,3,\dots$ such that $\Delta_N \geq 0$, $N=1,2,3,\dots$

Two factors that I have considered are:

1. The ordering of $\vec{\lambda}$ as increasing, decreasing or unordered (randomly ordered).
2. The range/dispersion of $\vec{\lambda}$. As noted with the Erlang distribution, if the range is zero then we have guaranteed convergence to a deterministic distribution.

In regard to the first point, increasing order seems to produce increasing behaviour for $\Psi(X_N)$ even if the range is large. This is shown in the figure below. I guess this is because it increases the likelihood that $\lambda_{N+1} > \lambda_{N+1}^*$.

[image: Increasing lambda]

With decreasing order, it would seem that the function inevitably starts to decrease. A wider range seems to just accelerates this. Perhaps a small enough range can ensure that it is always increasing.
[image: Decreasing lambda narrow range]

[image: Decreasing lambda wide range]

Here is what the $CV(X_N)$ looks like for the wide range, decreasing order case. Have a look at its tail. It starts to increase thus ruling out convergence to a deterministic distribution. With that said, the $CV(X_N)$ value is tiny such that one could consider it near deterministic at this point.
[image: CV plot of decreasing lambdas with large range]
Now we get to the random ordering. I present here only the plots for a wide range as we have already seen that small ranges lead to higher changes of $\Psi(X_N)$ increasing.

[image: Unordered high range]

As we've seen, this is not always the whole story. Here is what the resultant $CV(X_N)$ plot looks like.

[image: CV unordered high range]

Again, it does decrease to a point where we can consider it deterministic. We must thus conclude that the hypo-exponential distribution is not guaranteed to converge to a deterministic distribution as more phases are added. However, it typically does become more deterministic; especially if increasing $\lambda_i$ values are added.

**Python code**
Here is some code if you would like to replicate some of the plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm

def psi(lambdas):
    num = 0
    den = 0
    for lambda0 in lambdas:
        for lambda1 in lambdas:
            if lambda0 == lambda1:
                continue
            num += 1/(lambda0*lambda1)
        den += 1/lambda0**2
    return num/den
    
def cv(lambdas):
    lambdas = np.array(lambdas)
    var = (1/lambdas**2).sum()
    mean = (1/lambdas).sum()
    return var/mean**2
    
    
def experiment(N,func,
               lambda_range=(0,100),
               seed=123):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    lambdas = np.random.uniform(0.9,100,N) # no order
    lambdas = np.sort(lambdas)  # increasing
    lambdas = lambdas[::-1]  # decreasing
    results = []
    for n in tqdm(range(2,N+1)):
        results.append(func(lambdas[:n]))
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    ax.plot(range(2,N+1),results)
    ax.set_xlabel('$N$')
    return fig,ax
    
def psi_experiment(N,lambda_range=(0,100),seed=123):
    fig,ax = experiment(N,psi,lambda_range,seed)
    ax.set_ylabel('$\Psi(X_N)$')
    return fig,ax
    
def cv_experiment(N,lambda_range=(0,100),seed=123):
    fig,ax = experiment(N,cv,lambda_range,seed)
    ax.set_ylabel('$CV(X_N)$')
    return fig,ax
    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 300
    lambda_range = (0,10)
    seed = 123
    test_psi = True
    if test_psi:
        fig,ax = psi_experiment(N,lambda_range,seed)
    else:
        fig,ax = cv_experiment(N,lambda_range,seed)
```